# How do I remove the extra indentation in the bibliography section?

Tags: typst

When I create a [bibliography](https://typst.app/docs/reference/meta/bibliography/) in Typst (0.5.0) in anything but the IEEE style, the first line is missing its indent. How do I fix the formatting so this does not occur?

```
= References
#bibliography("bib.bib", style: "apa", title: none)
```

Sample content for the file `bib.bib`:

```
@Article{Einstein:1911:RGT,
  author =       "A. Einstein",
  title =        "{Die Relativit{\"a}tstheorie}. ({German}) [{The} Theory of Relativity]",
  journal =      j-VJSCHR-NATURF-GES-ZURICH,
  volume =       "56",
  pages =        "1--14",
  year =         "1911",
  ZMnumber =     "42.0720.02",
  acknowledgement = ack-nhfb,
  author-dates = "Albert Einstein (1879--1955)",
  Calaprice-number = "31",
  language =     "German",
  Schilpp-number = "43",
  ZMreviewer =   "Prof. Lampe (Berlin)",
}
```

All other lines are slightly indented compared to normal text:

[image: badly formed bibliography]

I would have expected all items to be consistently indented. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to create an empty `box` as a line between the header and the bibliography. This creates more vertical space, but eliminates the indent:

```
= References
#box[]
#bibliography("bib.bib", style: "apa", title: none)
```

[image: well-formed bibliography]